# Rails 3 asset pipeline: How to prevent some asset files from being loaded for everyone (eg. browser-specific)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline, rails-3.1

I want to server the 'excanvas.min.js' file only to the Internet Explorer and **not to other browsers**.

So I did in my `application.html.erb`:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'excanvas.min'
# Excanvas for use of Canvas in IE up to version 8
%>
<![endif]-->
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
```

But I get the following error (in production):

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms

ActionView::Template::Error (excanvas.min.js isn't precompiled)
```

The error also happens when forcing Rails to precompile the file with

```
# Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
config.assets.compile = false
config.assets.precompile += %W(excanvas.min.js,other_file.css,even_anotherfile.js)
```

in 'config/production.rb'. What am I doing wrong?

I could do a

```
//= require excanvas.min
```

in the `application.js`. But that would include the file for every browser...

*Info: I made an update from an Rails 3.0-Application.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the following line

```
config.assets.precompile += %W(excanvas.min.js,other_file.css,even_anotherfile.js)
```

the `%W` is a shortcut for creating an array, and the items need to be separated by a space. In your case you are adding the string `excanvas.min.js,other_file.css,even_anotherfile.js` to the precompile list.

So just replace the line as follows:

```
config.assets.precompile += %W(excanvas.min.js other_file.css even_anotherfile.js)
```

Answer (score 1):

just try to add <%# %> for line  and .
i think they will be displayed as comment.

OR

you can do that will js.judge the browser with js and load the corresponding css file

Comment: That is not usefull. I need the javascripts, so uncommenting them is not an option. Wolfgangs answer helped.